# ¿Como abrir un PDF en una nueva pestaña en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin, php7

Comunidad, me gustaría saber como puedo abrir una nueva pestaña en el navegador, tengo el siguiente código, pero me muestra el resultado en la misma venta, Quisiera que al dar clic, me mostrara el resultado en una nueva venta.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btnPrint", function (e) {
    window.location.href = './../Reports/orden.php?id=' + Number(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.sorting_1').textContent);
  });
```

Comment: ya ensayaste con `window.open`? o agregando `target="_blank"` al link?

Comment: ya, pero me lo abre en la misma ventana

Comment: no tiene sentido lo que dices... `window.open()` o `target="_blank"` abren en ventana nueva. Puedes actualizar tu pregunta y mostrar como los definiste? Porque podría no funcionarte si defines un `<a target="_blank">` pero igual le dejas el evento `click`... por eso digo que nos compartas las soluciones completas que has intentado. Por ejemplo, podrías también añadir en este momento que es `.btnPrint`... es un `<a>`, un `<button>` o que es?

Comment: btnPrint es un Botón que está en mi datatable que al presionar te manda a orden.php que es un reporte en PDF, pero me lo abre en misma ventana, y yo quisiera que me abriera en una pestaña nueva.

Comment: Por eso, agrega la solución completa con `window.open` que dices que no te funciona y la solución completa con `<a target="_blank">` que no te funciona para poder ayudarte... recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta inicial para incluir mas información.

Comment: No sé de qué manera implementar eso que dices bro, soy nuevo en JavaScritp disculpa mi ignorancia.

 $(document).on("click", ".btnPrint", function (e) {
   target="_blank" <a href= './../Reports/orden.php?id=' + Number(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.sorting_1').textContent);" target="_blank">
  });

asi me manda erro en las < >

Comment: y por lo visto también eres bastante nuevo en HTML. Te recomiendo primero estudiar las bases de cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Si, apenas estoy aprendiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Con la etiqueta `<a>` y un atributo `target="_blank"`

```
<a href= './../Reports/orden.php?id=' + Number(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.sorting_1').textContent);" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Es decir quedaria algo asi?

$(document).on("click", ".btnPrint", function (e) {
   target="_blank" <a href= './../Reports/orden.php?id=' + Number(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.sorting_1').textContent);" target="_blank">
  });

Comment: Me mando error, creo que es por las <>

Comment: no se que estoy haciendo mal, pero me manda error en el target